Assalamu Alaikum. Can we draw full body figures without facial features, like no eyes, mouth, or nose? Does this fall under haram or is it halal? Thnk
Assalamu Alaikum. Can we draw full body figures without facial features, like no eyes, mouth, or nose? Does this fall under haram or is it halal?

Maybe this can help answer your question: https://youtu.be/mjCLJ73_o-o?si=ijG1A7-MgE8rb5Bu
